# Excel 2016 Conditonal formatting and color scales

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I want to compare A10 with B10. If B10 is greater than A10 then I want both columns to be in red. I have looked at YT for solutions but there are only one dimension. I have also checked most common references w/o any luck. Do you have any good advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color scales will take into account all values in the range that the conditional format applies to and will then distribute the colors based on the value of each cell in relation to all other cells.

What you describe cannot be done with color scales but with a conditional formatting rule that uses a formula. Select both cells A10 and B10, create a new rule with this formula:

=$B10>$A10

Set the color to red. Note the $ sign in front of the column letter, but not the row number. When you copy the format to other rows, this relative row reference will then apply to the current row.